# PHP with SQL Server: strtotime() with SQL Server DATETIME column

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have SQL Server datetime field, and in PHP I want to use this as a UNIX TIMESTAMP, because I want to use it with strtotime, in order to add 14 days into it. Eg. If it is stored in the SQL Server database as: 2010-07-27 13:12:22.040    I want to add 14 days into it to become   2010-08-10 13:12:22.040

How would I do that using PHP with SQL Server datetime field? strtotime() command takes only UNIX timestamp.

If can't be done in PHP with SQL Server , how would I do it in SQL Server and then select it with the values I am selecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would I do it in SQL Server and then select it with the values I am selecting?

Use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 14, date_column)
```

...to add 14 days to the column value.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` takes a string date format, but anyway, you can also look into `mktime()`.

Comment: or do it directly in sql using adddate() or addtime()

Comment: Thanks, I used DATEADD instead